# React: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'year' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to create a calendar using react hooks, but I am getting the following error

```
Store.js:3661 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'year' of undefined
    at Function.diff (Store.js:3661)
    at Function.interval (Store.js:3674)
    at Store.js:88850
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at renderCalendarDays (Store.js:88849)
    at EventCalendar (Store.js:88867)
    at renderWithHooks (Store.js:47072)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (Store.js:49487)
    at beginWork$1 (Store.js:50836)
    at HTMLUnknownEl
```

Here is the function causing the problem, especially this line      `const isToday = Calendar.interval(day, today) === 1`;

> ```
> const  renderCalendarDays = ()=>{
>             return getDaysWithEvents().map((day, index) => {
>                 const isToday = Calendar.interval(day, today) === 1;
>                 console.log(isToday)
>                 const events = renderEvents(day);
>
>                 return (
>                     <CalendarDay 
>                         key={'day_'+getSerializedDay(day)}
>                         day={day} 
>                         events={events}
>                         isToday={isToday} 
>                         onClick={props.onDayClick}
>                         onMouseOut={props.onEventMouseOut}
>                         onMouseOver={props.onEventMouseOver}
>                         />
>                     );
>             });
>         }
> ```

Unfortunately, I am struggling to solve the problem, can someone help me out?

What is wrong with my code here?

Comment: which line has error? reducer, than post reducer code

Comment: @xdeepakv this const isToday = Calendar.interval(day, today) === 1;

Comment: Where do you EventCalendar component? You don't pass year in props.

Comment: can you add `console.log("day", day)` inside getSerializedDay function and tell me if day is not null

Comment: @Quantumass https://ibb.co/SVyKzv4

Comment: @hurricane am using in another component

Comment: anyone interested to contribute checks out my repo https://github.com/throne1986/Calendar

Comment: props will be undefined check it in getCalendarDays function

Comment: @Quantumass the problem is today when I do console.log(today) when I call renderCalendays function its undefined, so meaning the function getToday function is not called properly , am struggling with check the getToday function

Comment: @Quantumass I have added the repo u can clone it and chek out

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood you assign an `Object` to the default value of your `today` state. Let's consider that your object is something like this with some dummy data: `{day:1, month:2, year:3}`. Now, if you want to access any of the properties of this object you will need to call for example: `today.day` not just `today`.